# UILocalNotification and alertLaunchImage

Tags: uilocalnotification

Hmmm……

A question about UILocalNotification and the notificaton's alertLaunchImage.

My app uses UILocalNotifiaction(s) to get users' attention.  As usual, an alert is presented with "Action" and "Close" buttons.  When the user taps Action, the image specified by alertLaunchImage is  presented.  The alertLaunchImage is a screenshot of of one of the views of the app which is shown after the data is initialized when launched normally.

Here are the 3 cases when the notification is delivered:

1. App is running in foreground - no alert, no launchImage is shown as designed.  No problems.
2. If my app is running in background when the notification is delivered, the launchImage works like a charm. No problems.  The launchImage with no app-related data is shown and then the app fills up the data. This part works seamlessly.
3. However, if the app is not running when the notification is delivered, the sequence is confusing - or I  missed something.  The app gets launched and shows the alertLaunchImage instead of the Default image.  Then is goes thru several other screens (as part of initialization and data processing) before the actual screen (live version of alertLaunchImage) is shown.

This can get very confusing to the user.   My question comes in here.  How can this be avoided?

R/-
Sam.!

[image: An intermediate view]
[image: alertLaunchImage]

Answer (score 0):

you can try cleaning up the alert view settings in **applicationWillTerminate:**

According to the *UIApplicationDelegate* reference **applicationWillTerminate:**:

> "This method lets your application know
>   that it is about to be terminated and
>   purged from memory entirely. You
>   should use this method to perform any
>   final clean-up tasks for your
>   application, such as freeing shared
>   resources, saving user data,
>   invalidating timers, and storing
>   enough application state to
>   reconstitute your application’s
>   interface when it is relaunched"

HTH,

Oded

Comment: Thanks Oded: I am a little confused....Your suggestion is about Alerts, and I was looking for information about LocalNotifications.

Comment: I was refering to the alertLaunchImage - you can reset it as you wish in applicationWillTerminate - to make sure it doesn't come up with an old frame and then restarts the app.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is launched by a local notification, you will receive that notification in the `options` passed to `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. Based on that, you can write code that navigates to the correct screen without animations.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{  
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotification != nil) {
        // startup by local notification
    } else {
        // normal startup
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will explore this option.

Comment: Did not quite work.  At the time the notification is delivered and the app is not running, if the user opts to respond to the notification, the default image is shown - launchImage is not shown.  Is that normal?  I have code similar to your sample above, but I thought that specifying the launchImage in the notification  was enough to get that behavior...

Comment: If you start/reactivate the app from the local notification, the `launchImage` of the notification should be shown. If you start it using the app icon, the `launchImage` of the local notification should not be shown. I just checked this with a small sample app and it works fine for me, and in your question, you described it worked for you as well (point 3 of your description). What have you changed since then?

Comment: Well, referring pint 3 of my original question: I have pro and free versions of the app, and they share the same code. The pro version works as intended; however, for the free app, when it is launched from the notification, the behavior is as I mentioned in my comment above on Jul 6.

Comment: Make sure that the basic version includes the launch image file as well, and that the launch image is set in the notification. Something has to be different between the two versions! :)